# Information Disclosure Statement for counterpart foreign application

Tags: uspto, pct, ids

I filed a PCT application in 2019.

I also filed a US patent application WITHOUT claiming priority from the PCT application in 2019.  I received "Written Opinion of the International Search Authority" in 2019. The examiner referenced few patent applications in the search report.

[37 CFR 1.97 (e) says](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s609.html),

> (e) A statement under this section must state either:
>
> (1) That each item of information contained in the information
> disclosure statement was first cited in any communication from a
> foreign patent office in a counterpart foreign application not more
> than three months prior to the filing of the information disclosure
> statement; or
>
> (2) That no item of information contained in the information
> disclosure statement was cited in a communication from a foreign
> patent office in a counterpart foreign application, and, to the
> knowledge of the person signing the certification after making
> reasonable inquiry, no item of information contained in the
> information disclosure statement was known to any individual
> designated in § 1.56(c) more than three months prior to the filing of
> the information disclosure statement.

I have not received first office action for my US application. The status says "Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination".

I have few questions:

1. It seems like I have to disclose "counterpart foreign application". I believe my PCT application would fall under "counterpart foreign application" category. Is that correct?
2. Since I have not received the first office action, do I have to pay any fees if I disclose the references cited by ISA examiner?
3. Do I have to add any certification statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is before the first [actions on the merit](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s609.html) there are no fees due of any certificate needed. You already may know that it is best practice to error on the side of disclosure.

Comment: I was really nervous before your answer. You made me ease. Thanks :-)